# Init a calss inside a class

Tags: library

I'm building a monitoring IP class, `IPmonitoring`, that using an SPIFFS class that I wrote, `flashLOG`. Inside `IPmonitoring` I have 2 instances of `flashLOG` (code below).

My sketch have several instances of `IPmonitoring` for several servicesI wish to monitor. I Wish that `connectionLOG` and `disconnectionLOG` have unique and automated names.

For example if I'm monitoring a service called `MQTT` its connect and disconnect log will be `MQTT_discolog.txt` and `MQTT_conlog.txt`. In my code below, `filename1` and  `filename2` are consts.

```
class IPmonitoring
{
private:
        char *_IP;
        char *_nick;

        flashLOG connectionLOG;
        flashLOG disconnectionLOG;

public:
        IPmonitoring(char *IP, char *nick, char *filename1 = "/conlog.txt", char *filename2 = "/disconlog.txt")
            : connectionLOG(filename1), disconnectionLOG(filename2)
        {
                _IP = IP;
                _nick = nick;
        }
```

**EDIT1 - example how to use class**

my goal is that `filename1` for example will be `MQTTbroker_connlog.txt` meaning a combination of `_nick` and a suffix,

```
IPmonitoring MQTT_service("192.168.3.200","MQTTbroker");

void setup()
{
MQTT_service.start();
}

void loop()
{
MQTT_service.loop();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the variable names in the source code? Any reason why you want this and not use a member in the class flashLOG, initialized by its constructor, to retain its name?

Comment: @Sacha yes, ` filename1` + `filename2`. I don't understand what is your suggestion, since this is the way `flashLOG` inits ( with a filename )

Comment: Forget about my first comment. In your example, how would the code creating the IPmonitoring instance know the name of the service it will monitor?

Comment: @Sacha - In a case I have more than one instance, using `filename1` and `filename2` in shown manner will over run each other - it is a not valid way to do so, unless I write each ones name in specific

Comment: you have the filenames as parameters. so construct it with different filenames

Comment: Please show us some example how you like to use the class `IPmonitoring`.

Comment: @thebusybee see edit 1

Comment: @Juraj see edit1

Comment: If you let the caller provide the complete filenames, the task would be quite simpler. I see this as a reasonable decision. -- Oh, and since you are programming in C++, the usage of `std::string` instead of C strings (`char[]`) _can_ make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your example usage, you want the filenames to be built by
the `IPmonitoring` constructor. However, since that class cannot know in
advance how much space is needed for the file names, you are left with
two choices:

1. Let those file names be data members: arrays of `char` of some fixed
   size. This will impose a limit on the maximum file name length.
2. Allocate the arrays dynamically at construction time.

Here is a tentative implementation of the second approach:

```cpp
class IPmonitoring
{
private:
    const char *_IP;
    const char *_nick;
    const char *connectionLOG_filename;
    const char *disconnectionLOG_filename;
    flashLOG connectionLOG;
    flashLOG disconnectionLOG;

    // Return a dynamically allocated string with the concatenation
    // of `a' and `b'.
    const char *str_concat(const char *a, const char *b)
    {
        char *s = new char[strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1];
        strcpy(s, a);
        strcat(s, b);
        return s;
    }

public:
    IPmonitoring(const char *IP, const char *nick)
        : _IP(IP), _nick(nick),
        connectionLOG_filename(str_concat(nick, "_connlog.txt")),
        disconnectionLOG_filename(str_concat(nick, "_disconnlog.txt")),
        connectionLOG(connectionLOG_filename),
        disconnectionLOG(disconnectionLOG_filename)
    {}

    ~IPmonitoring(){
        delete[] connectionLOG_filename;
        delete[] disconnectionLOG_filename;
    }
};
```

Note the destructor, which is needed to avoid memory leaks, unless all
the instances of the class are statically allocated (which would be good
to avoid memory fragmentation). You may want to implement a copy
constructor and a copy assignment operator, as per the [rule of
three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: Can you please explain `: _IP(IP), _nick(nick)` I never used such syntax

Comment: @Guy.D: It means “Initialize `_IP` with the value of `IP`”. It is functionally equivalent to the assignment you used in the constructor, but it is syntactically an initialization rather than an assignment. It is here intended to make clear that the constructor does nothing more than initialize the data members.

Comment: great! Didn’t know it

Comment: Can you please explain/ give an example for static allocate of class ?

Comment: @Guy.D: See your own usage example: the object is a global variable, and global variables are statically allocated. In this case the constructor is called at program startup, before `main()`, and the destructor is normally never called.

Comment: OK, just wanted to be sure your mean.

Comment: 1. Would it make sense to use C++ strings (`std::string`) that can be dynamically concatenated? -- 2. Beginning with C++14 the rule to obey is the [Rule of Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)#Rule_of_Five).

Answer (score 1):

You have three options for the file names and generally.

1. constant string a.k.a. string literal
2. string buffer global or on stack with scope valid while the string is used
3. dynamically allocated string on heap

with 2) and 3) you can then build a string with C str or sprintf functions

option 3) is alright on MCU if you create these file names only at startup, not if you create them repeatedly as the sketch is running

If you choose option 3) you can build the strings in the constructor of IPmonitoring class, but you can't build the string in the member initialization part of the constructor. You have to add setters to `flashLOG` class and after building the strings for file names set them to the `flashLOG` instance with the setters.

Comment: @Guy.D I enhanced the answer